# Referencing the Shared Context in Power Query SDK

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Im attempting to build a custom data connector for Power BI based on this [ms docs connectors tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/startingtodevelopcustomconnectors) using Visual Studio Community 2019 with Power Query SDK V1.0.0.25. However, when I attempt to run the project query fike in Visual Studio I receive an error stating 
`"The name MyProjectName.Contents()"` cannot be found in the current context...

I've searched the [Power Query Spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-language-specification) for a solution with no resolve yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### **MyProjectName.query.pq**

```
let
    result = ProjectName.Contents()

in
    result
```

### **MyProjectName.pq**

```
// This file contains your Data Connector logic
section MyProjectName;

oktaEndpoint="XXX";
oktaServerId="XXX";
oktaClientId= "XXX";
redirect_uri = "https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html" ;
windowHeight = "600";
windowWidth = "1000";

[DataSource.Kind="MyProjectName", Publish="MyProjectName.Publish"]
shared MyProjectName.Contents = (optional message as text) =>
    let
        _message = if (message <> null) then message else "(no message)",
        a = "Hello from MyProjectName: " & _message
    in
        a;

StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) =>
let
    authorizeUrl = Text.Format(
    "#[oktaEndpoint]/oauth2/#[oktaServerId]/v1/authorize?", [oktaEndpoint = oktaEndpoint, oktaServerId = oktaServerId]) & 
    Uri.BuildQueryString([
        response_type = "code",
        scope = "openid",
        client_id = oktaClientId,
        redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
        state = state
    ])
in
    [
        LoginUri = authorizeUrl,
        CallbackUri = redirect_uri,
        WindowHeight = windowHeight,
        WindowWidth = windowWidth,
        Context = null
    ];

FinishLogin = [];

// Data Source Kind description
MyProjectName= [
    Authentication = [
        // Key = [],
        // UsernamePassword = [],
        // Windows = [],
        //Implicit = [],
        OAuth = [
        StartLogin = StartLogin,
        FinishLogin = FinishLogin
//        Refresh = Refresh,
//        Logout = Logout
        ]
    ],
    Label = Extension.LoadString("DataSourceLabel")
];



// Data Source UI publishing description
MyProjectName.Publish = [
    Beta = true,
    Category = "Other",
    ButtonText = { Extension.LoadString("ButtonTitle"), Extension.LoadString("ButtonHelp") },
    LearnMoreUrl = "https://powerbi.microsoft.com/",
    SourceImage = MyProjectName.Icons,
    SourceTypeImage = MyProjectName.Icons
];

MyProjectName.Icons = [
    Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("MyProjectName16.png"), Extension.Contents("MyProjectName20.png"), Extension.Contents("MyProjectName24.png"), Extension.Contents("MyProjectName32.png") },
    Icon32 = { Extension.Contents("MyProjectName32.png"), Extension.Contents("MyProjectName40.png"), Extension.Contents("MyProjectName48.png"), Extension.Contents("MyProjectName64.png") }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me as well. You don't seem to have any errors.
Your shared function is correctly associated with the DataSource Kind and the names are the same, it seems.

I suggest you **rebuild the project** and **restart Visual Studio**. It worked many times for me.

If it doesn't work, try using the connector in Power BI as is, to see if there is anything missing that we are not seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance but I've tried that as well as creating a new project and the results are the same... Further, the presenter's project in the MS video, [Microsoft Power BI: Building connectors - BRK4003](https://youtu.be/srQ-DLqhoxM?t=778) displays the same error as I'm having and he didn't provide the solution...